# Error al intentar usar la herramienta "Summaryplot" del paquete "Openair"

Tags: r

Estoy trabajando una base de datos de contaminación atmosférica que tiene los datos de contaminantes y su respectiva concentración. Sin embargo, al intentar usar la herramienta *"SummaryPlot"* de *"Openair"* me sale el siguiente error:

**Error: Each row of output must be identified by a unique combination of keys.
Keys are shared for 5151479 rows**

He intentado corregir el error con **tibble::rowid_to_column()**

Sin embargo, no me ha solucionado el problema, pues me vuelve a salir el mismo error.

Agradezco si me pueden indicar una solución a mi problema, pues necesito usar el paquete "Openair"

````
   rowid date                Value site  EnvAut Latitude Longitude AveragingTimeHo~
   <int> <dttm>              <dbl> <chr> <chr>     <dbl>     <dbl>            <dbl>
 1     1 2008-01-01 00:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 2     2 2008-01-01 01:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 3     3 2008-01-01 02:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 4     4 2008-01-01 03:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 5     5 2008-01-01 04:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 6     6 2008-01-01 05:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 7     7 2008-01-01 06:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 8     8 2008-01-01 07:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
 9     9 2008-01-01 08:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
10    10 2008-01-01 09:00:00    NA AGUI~ A.M. ~     6.25     -75.6                1
# ... with 5,533,834 more rows, and 8 more variables: Year <dbl>, Var <chr>,
#   Units <chr>, COD_DEP <dbl>, NOM_DEP <chr>, COD_MUN <dbl>, NOM_MUN <chr>,
#   StationType <chr> ```
````

Comment: Hola Laura, ¿es el error al hacer spread()? si es eso, ciertamente es un error consecuencia de como están los datos. raro que no te haya funcionado el rowid_to_column() en principio, ¿podrías compartir el código, por si vemos algo raro?

Comment: Hola Patricio, muchas gracias por responderme nuevamente. ¿Cómo les podría compartir el código? Que pena contigo, es que soy muy nueva usando el programa.

Comment: La idea siempre es resumir la parte esencial que hace a la pregunta y copiarlo en el mismo cuerpo de la pregunta (puedes editarla cuando quieras).

Comment: Hola Patricio, discúlpame, pero no he entendido. ¿Qué necesitas para que puedas ver el código y si hay algo raro?

Comment: Laura, idealmente pediríamos que armes un [mcve], pero viendo que tienes más de 5 millones de registros, no voy a pedirte los datos, pero al menos tendríamos que ver cual es el código R que estás ejecutando y fundamentalmente cual es la instrucción que ta el error. Saludos.